# Better reg ex for matching 8 sets of 4 alphanumerics?

Tags: regex, string, pattern-matching, string-matching

I am looking for a reg ex to parse codes that look like this:

```
TEDL 9V1J 5K1Y EQFF NSA1 CF4T 8NQU UZL1
```

I have this regex, which works, but I would be grateful to understand how to make it more concise.

```
[A-Z0-9]{4}\s[A-Z0-9]{4}\s[A-Z0-9]{4}\s[A-Z0-9]{4}\s[A-Z0-9]{4}\s[A-Z0-9]{4}\s[A-Z0-9]{4}\s[A-Z0-9]{4}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this `\s[A-Z0-9]{4}` regex into a non-capturing group and add `{7}` after that to make the pattern to repeat for exactly 7 times.

```
^[A-Z0-9]{4}(?:\s[A-Z0-9]{4}){7}$
```

OR

```
\b[A-Z0-9]{4}(?:\s[A-Z0-9]{4}){7}\b
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/mE0iP1/2)

Answer (score 0):

You can use refactory your regex to:

```
\b((?:[A-Z0-9]{4}(?: |$)){8})
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/pI1oK2/1)

Comment: Yes it does and there is nothing wrong as per question (see OP's original regex)

Answer (score 0):

```
(([A-Z0-9]{4})\s){7}([A-Z0-9]{4})
```